# Web services consumption management - best practices

Tags: c#, web-services, design-patterns, web, infrastructure

I'm building an infrastructure for several websites.
I want to make a generic/abstract infrastructure for managing web services.

Lets say I want to give the user the ability to translate a text..
I want to have several web services available, sorted from best to worst - if the first fails then the second one kicks in.

I want to make it as dynamic as possible.

What best practices do you think of? And why?

I was thinking of some service locator mutation with a common dll with all interfaces, a directory for each service type with dlls that each introduce a different service for the same porpose (I can give each one a score to sort by).. A service locator class will know to use reflection to find those dlls on Application_Start or somewhere else.. Is it a good start?

Comment: Your scenario looks like the perfect opportunity to implement MEF. http://mef.codeplex.com/. It is now part of the .Net framework 4.0

Comment: Oded - Sorry, but I think my question is not too broad, I said exactly what I wanted and I asked for opinions and best practices.. I even gave my starting idea..
HighCore - Thanks for the reference, I'm checking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to HighCore I've looked into Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) and it seems to answer a big part of my needs.. The others are pretty simple to implement..

I found some great and simple information here:
http://randomactsofcoding.blogspot.co.il/2009/11/working-with-managed-extensibility.html?m=1